# VS Mac doesn't debug my Xamarin Android App after I have installed Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, adb, visual-studio-2019

After I have installed Android Studio on my Mac, my xamarin apps no longer runs on my Visual Studio. The application output only now displays `Forwarding Debugger Port ####`. And my deploying to devices just builds the csproj. I am just over a year now with C#.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

My Visual Studio version is 2019 8.3 Professional.

Comment: Hi , do you mean VS for mac can not debug the android app ?

Comment: Yes, I have a Xamarin Android I have developed on VS. Then after installing Android Studio and running some apps there, the VS doesn't run the app anymore

Comment: Okey , is there other detail logs about it ?

Comment: No logs unfortunately, the only log is saw in the application output is "Forwarding Debugger Port ####"

Comment: And my deploying to devices just builds the csproj

Comment: Okey , you can have a try with restarting adb In VS , **choose Tools** -> **Android** -> **Restart Adb Server** . Also you can restart adb in Terminal wirh command code , you can searh methods in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is weird because after I restarted the Mac, it worked again for some reason.

Comment: Great , you can share it in answer and then mark it later :)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if it is much of an answer though with the restart.

Comment: Yeah ,don't worry . You can update it as an answer , no matter what this way solve the problem . Attach some detailed explanations, such as trying this method first, then another method, and finally solving the problem by restarting. And later people occur this phenomenon , it will be helpful for them. :)

Comment: Ok I will try to do that. Thanks a lot of the help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seemed to work again after restarting. I have opened my Visual Studio first and not the Android Studio.